# How to count # of matching unique keys of an object (javascript)

Tags: javascript, object, key, unique

I'm trying to get the unique keys of an object, add the values and count how many of the unique key there are of each, but can't figure out a graceful solution.

raw array of objs:

```
[{
    "2017W40": 15.25
}, {
    "2017W40": 16.5
}, {
    "2017W40": 16.6
}, {
    "2017W40": 11
}, {
    "2017W40": 17.857142857142858
}, {
    "2017W40": 13
}, {
    "2017W41": 19
}, {
    "2017W41": 20.25
}, {
    "2017W41": 18.25
}, {
    "2017W41": 13
}, {
    "2017W41": 20.333333333333332
}, {
    "2017W41": 20.5
}, {
    "2017W41": 20.5
}, {
    "2017W42": 19.5
}, {
    "2017W42": 19.5
}, {
    "2017W42": 20
}, {
    "2017W42": 19.5
}, {
    "2017W42": 19.333333333333332
}, {
    "2017W42": 20
}, {
    "2017W42": 20.5
}, {
    "2017W43": 20
}, {
    "2017W43": 20
}, {
    "2017W43": 19.666666666666668
}, {
    "2017W43": 19.6
}, {
    "2017W43": 19.666666666666668
}, {
    "2017W43": 19
}, {
    "2017W43": 19.5
}, {
    "2017W44": 21
}, {
    "2017W44": 19.5
}, {
    "2017W44": 20
}, {
    "2017W44": 19.5
}]
```

summed object:

```
{
    "2017W40": 90.20714285714286,
    "2017W41": 131.83333333333331,
    "2017W42": 138.33333333333331,
    "2017W43": 137.43333333333334,
    "2017W44": 80
}
```

But I'd also like to include a count of each (so I can get an average instead of just the sum)   Here is the method I"m using:

```
function getValueAvg(valsByKey) {
  const dateObj = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < valsByKey.length; ++i) {
    for (const obj in valsByKey[i]) {
      if (dateObj[obj]) {
        // add them if exists already
        dateObj[obj] = dateObj[obj] + valsByKey[i][obj];
      } else {
        // first
        dateObj[obj] = valsByKey[i][obj];
      }
    }
  }
```

So either a final object of

```
{
    {"2017W40": 90.20714285714286, count:x},
    {"2017W41": 131.83333333333331, count:x},
    {"2017W42": 138.33333333333331, count:x},
    {"2017W43": 137.43333333333334, count:x},
    {"2017W44": 80, count:x}
}
```

or just the value divided by count would work wonders for me.
"2017W40": 90.20714285714286/count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create new objects that has two fields, a value or sum field, and a count field. When you iterate over the data, you just add into the value field and then up the count by one.

```js
function getValueAvg(valsByKey) {
  const dateObj = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < valsByKey.length; ++i) {
    for (const obj in valsByKey[i]) {
      if (dateObj[obj]) {
        // add them if exists already
        dateObj[obj].val = dateObj[obj].val + valsByKey[i][obj];
        dateObj[obj].count += 1;
      } else {
        // first
        dateObj[obj] = {"val":valsByKey[i][obj], "count":1};
      }
    }
  }
  return dateObj;
}

var data = [{
  "2017W40": 15.25
}, {
  "2017W40": 16.5
}, {
  "2017W40": 16.6
}, {
  "2017W40": 11
}, {
  "2017W40": 17.857142857142858
}, {
  "2017W40": 13
}, {
  "2017W41": 19
}, {
  "2017W41": 20.25
}, {
  "2017W41": 18.25
}, {
  "2017W41": 13
}, {
  "2017W41": 20.333333333333332
}, {
  "2017W41": 20.5
}, {
  "2017W41": 20.5
}, {
  "2017W42": 19.5
}, {
  "2017W42": 19.5
}, {
  "2017W42": 20
}, {
  "2017W42": 19.5
}, {
  "2017W42": 19.333333333333332
}, {
  "2017W42": 20
}, {
  "2017W42": 20.5
}, {
  "2017W43": 20
}, {
  "2017W43": 20
}, {
  "2017W43": 19.666666666666668
}, {
  "2017W43": 19.6
}, {
  "2017W43": 19.666666666666668
}, {
  "2017W43": 19
}, {
  "2017W43": 19.5
}, {
  "2017W44": 21
}, {
  "2017W44": 19.5
}, {
  "2017W44": 20
}, {
  "2017W44": 19.5
}]

console.log(getValueAvg(data));
```